# Mod rewrite remove query string after trailing slash

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Quick question I want to 404 any url which adds a query string after a trailing slash in a url. Is this possible?

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [R=404,L]
```

But it isn't working any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you could try this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteRule /$ - [R=404,L]
```

The `RewriteCond` checks if query string is not empty, and the `RewriteRule` checks if it ends with a `/`.

Or you could use the request directly like this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.+/)?\? [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
```

Comment: The second method is probably more accurate if you had to choose.